Django Profile Page Not Displaying Related Worker Information with Djoser
I'm working on a Django application where users can be either normal app users or workers with additional details. I'm using Djoser for user authentication and registration. I'm having trouble with my profile page, which is supposed to display both user and worker information, but it only shows user information.
Here's a brief overview of my code:
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .managers import CustomUserManager

class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First name'), max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("User")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Users")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class Worker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='workers')
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    pricePerHour = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    gender_choices = [
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    ]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender_choices)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    num_tel = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    small_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.email} - {self.num_tel}"


#views.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import Category, Worker
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer
from djoser.serializers import UserSerializer as DjoserUserSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers



User = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

class WorkerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()  # Serialize user details

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = '__all__' 


class CustomUserSerializer(DjoserUserSerializer):
    worker = WorkerSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta(DjoserUserSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'worker']

class CreateUserSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']


class CategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class ProvidersSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()  # Include detailed user information

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = '__all__'

#DJOSER SETTINGS:
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    "USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE": True,
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'base.serializers.CreateUserSerializer',
        'user': 'base.serializers.CustomUserSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    },  
}

Problem:
When I make a GET request to api/v1/auth/users/me/, the response only includes the user information (userInfo) and does not include the related worker information (workerInfo). I have verified that the worker instance exists and is correctly associated with the user.
Steps Taken:
Verified that the Worker instance exists for the user.
Confirmed the request includes a valid JWT token.
Checked database relationships to ensure they are correctly set up.
Question:
What might be causing the workerInfo not to appear in the profile response, and how can I resolve this issue with Djoser?

i found the answer in the djoser documentation
apparently i forgot to add the 'current_user' in the djoser settings
by adding it:
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    "USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE": True,
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'base.serializers.CreateUserSerializer',
        'user': 'base.serializers.CustomUserSerializer',
        'current_user': 'base.serializers.CustomUserSerializer', ==> here
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    },  
}

it worked like a charm!!
